# Neo4j: Storing standard non graph data (i.e. application settings)?

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jclient

I have just started using neo4j to store data in a graph, i.e. friends of friends etc..

But now I need to store standard application configuration data. This isn't graph data really, its settings that the application will use to help it run.

Normally I would store this in a table in a RDMS or in a document in MongoDB.

Can I still store this data in neo4j ? or should I use another database to store it?

Is it beneficial to have 2 databases i.e. neo4j and mongodb ??  Pros and Cons?

Anybody done anything like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is really an opinion-seeking question, regarding making a choice of data store for application settings. You can store app settings in any database engine you choose to. You'd need to draw your own conclusions, based on your own environment, whether a multi-engine solution is required or efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to store it in Neo4j, if it is not large binary data.
Then I'd store it in a blob storage and just store references to it.

If you have nested structures you can either decompose them into multiple nodes, use property prefixes or serialize them to a string (e.g. JSON).